# XRay failing with self-signed cert

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

I'm doing a helm install of JFrog XRay and I'm running into a snag. We have Artifactory installed internally using a company self-signed cert and XRay won't come up because of it. The router component fails with 'certificate signed by unknown authority'. How do I get past this issue? Is there a method for injecting the root cert into the container?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is Xray 3.x installation connecting with Artifactory 7.x and if som based on this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Managing+TLS+Certificates#ManagingTLSCertificates-TrustingaSelf-SignedCertificateoraNewCA), you need to pass the self-signed certificate under the location $JFROG_HOME/xray/var/etc/security/keys/trusted directory and as this is a helm based install and I think a k8 secrets should be created and passed in that mentioned location. Also, refer to this [github](https://github.com/jfrog/charts/tree/master/stable/xray#establishing-tls-and-adding-certificates).

Answer (score 0):

As Xray is written in Go, you can pass the self-signed certificates by placing them in /etc/ssl/certs/ and restarting Xray.